# make Website restriction or block website in hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, blocking, wireless-hotspot

I have E5573Cs-609 device from HUAWEI. This is wifi hotspot device. My requirement is when other devices are connected then users should not view website like fb,youtube. I tried but not working. Some one please help me. This may helpful to some other also.
I will appreciate if provide step by step process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are already a lot of guides for something like this available and short of giving the device you haven't supplied any additional information. What have you tried? What didn't work? What other infrastructure do you have in place?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried with available menu options but it showing ip filters.

Comment: In that case it's probably not able to do this on it's own. Usually you would use higher level filtering or a proxy for this. If you have a separate router attached to it to get the actual internet access check that device as well for possible settings.